# How to configure NGINX proxy_pass with Angular 2 PathLocationStrategy

Tags: nginx

I am currently serving my Angular 2 front-end with PM2, running at a the ip address `http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/`. When using Angular 2's `HashLocationStrategy`, non-root paths reload fine. When using `PathLocationStrategy`, refreshes do not work. Is there a way to pass the path through the `proxy_pass` in the `location /` so that a path like `/about` with resolve to the `/about` provided by the Angular 2 router?

My current set up will successfully go from `/` to `/about` in the application, but if I refresh the `/about`, it returns a blank page:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    root http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/;
    server_name _;
    index index.htm index.html;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://198.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/;
    }

    location ^~ /api/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server/api/;
    }
}
```

Here are my PM2 logs for visiting `/`, then clicking a link to visit `/about`, then refreshing the `/about` page:

```
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 14:59:38 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 14:59:38 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /polyfills.c4ffdebfdb7d4e9ee964.bundle.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 14:59:38 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /main.4916a64a8641d387872b.bundle.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 14:59:39 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /assets/img/dailydownbeat_icon.svg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 14:59:39 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /a35720c2fed2c7f043bc7e4ffb45e073.woff" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 15:00:02 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /about" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
dailydownbeat-0 [Sat Mar 05 2016 15:00:02 GMT-0500 (EST)] "GET /about" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: A blank page usually means your Node.js server had an exception. Check its logs.

Comment: I just added the logs from PM2. It just gives a 404 on refresh.